# Smoothly switching animations on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I am working on a project that calls for multiple animated, moving icons that will stop, expand, and move to position on mouseover. Is there a pure CSS way to get an element to seamlessly start from whatever (mid-animation) position they are at when the hover event begins and transition to the new final keyframe properties, rather than starting from a set initial state?

```
@keyframes drop {
from {top:-100px;}
to {top:100px;}
}
@keyframes freeze {
to {left:10px;  width:700px;}
}

.droptext {
position:absolute; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
animation: drop 2s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: drop 2s linear infinite;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: width 2s;
}
.droptext:hover { 
z-index:99; 
-webkit-animation: freeze 2s linear 1s forwards; 
-webkit-transition: top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.droptext:hover {
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animation-play-state: paused` to pause the animation and expand the text on `:hover` with transition. Example:

```css
@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: 200px;
    left: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  animation: drop 10s linear infinite;
}
.text:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blah blah</div>
```

Comment: But is there any way to get it to move from whatever position it was hovered over at to the top (or any set vertical position), in a smooth animated manner?

Comment: Check my edited answer. It's expand and move from it was hovered.